# How to produce the loudest sound possible on a J2ME phone?

Tags: audio, java-me, alert, nokia, mmapi

I have a midlet that upon discovering something displays some information, vibrates, flashes the screen, and makes a sound - all to get the user's attention. The problem is that the sound is not loud enough.

how do i make the phone produce the loudest sound it can ? I prefer not to add a sound file unless that's the key. I prefer to use standard j2me library, but can settle for Nokia's library if absolutely needed.

I am mainly targeting Nokia S60 or S40.

currently, the best i can come up with is this:

```
Manager.playTone(ToneControl.C4, duration, 100);
```

But you can hardly hear the sound this makes on some phones.

Comment: you can write that playTone() method in while loop for more effect

Comment: yes, i can add different tones, and actually play a little tune, but the volume is so low that it can't be heard on S40 phones that i have. (on S60 the tone is louder). it would be good if i could trigger the currently selected ringing sound

Comment: you just have to set proper pitch.

Comment: I use this code Manager.playTone( 100 , 500, 100 ); in for look with 5 iteration